# Rails App on Ubuntu running Apache and Passenger throws 404 with params

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to set up a server to host my rails apps. I have one I am testing and it is giving me a 404 error when I call a controller action while passing params in the URL. I have this app deployed on Heroku and it runs perfectly. Any action that is called without params work perfectly on the new server. It is only the action that passes the params that is giving me the 404.

Also I ran it locally with Webrick on the server and it works fine. It only has this issue when running on passenger.

Any ideas what might cause this or where I should start to find the issue?

This is the request being sent
Request GET /groups/2/set_and_redirect/%2Fgroups%2F2%2Fgroups_lists HTTP/1.1

This is the body of the 404 response
The requested URL /groups/2/set_and_redirect//groups/2/groups_lists was not found on this server.

Edit

This is the partial that is causing the issue. Specificaly the link_to group.name. The edit and delete both work fine and the set and redirect works fine on Heroku and Webrick.

```html
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <h4><div>
      <%= link_to group.name, groups_set_and_redirect_path(:id => group.id, :path => group_list_path(id: group.id) ), remote: true %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%= link_to ('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>').html_safe, edit_group_path(group),'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "#group-modal#{group.id}", remote: true %>&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <%= link_to ('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i>').html_safe, group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
    </div></h4>
<%end%>
<div> <%= link_to ('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-success"></i>').html_safe, "#group-modal", 'data-toggle' => 'modal', class: 'btn btn-lg' %> </div>
```

> I changed my route from
>
> get 'groups/:id/set_and_redirect/:path' => 'groups#set_and_redirect',
>   :as => :groups_set_and_redirect
>
> to
>
> get 'groups/:id/set_and_redirect' => 'groups#set_and_redirect', :as =>
>   :groups_set_and_redirect
>
> and now it works

Comment: that double slash between `set_and_redirect` and `groups` looks problematic. What does the view look like that generates this request?

Comment: @SeanHuber I agree that looks like were the issue is, but why does passing params in the url cause that? It works fine on Heroku and when I run it on Webrick.

Comment: It depends, Apache might be rewriting the url to remove the double slash or have slash arguments enabled. I don't think changing the Apache config is your desired solution though. You should instead adjust your `routes.rb` so that a double slash doesn't occur (perhaps by using a named parameter for `path`). Could you also show us your route definition for the `set_and_redirect` in `routes.rb`?

Comment: Thank you that was the issue.
I had origionaly tried to pass the path in the url its self and did not remove that from the url when I changed it to pass it as a param.

I changed it from
`
get 'groups/:id/set_and_redirect/:path' => 'groups#set_and_redirect', :as => :groups_set_and_redirect
`
to
`
get 'groups/:id/set_and_redirect' => 'groups#set_and_redirect', :as => :groups_set_and_redirect
`
and it works fine now.

Comment: Excellent! Would you mind accepting my answer then? I'm trying to get my reputation points up :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your `routes.rb` so that a double slash doesn't occur (perhaps by using a named parameter for `path`).